# Create Java exception when String is entered instead of integer

Tags: java, swing, exception, netbeans

I have to create a calculator application at school and the calculator is working fine, but now I have to create an exception that shows a user friendly message when the user enters a string instead of an integer value.

This is the code I have now with a JFrame and everything:

```
private void minActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String invoerEen = getalEen.getText();
    int invoerEenDef =  Integer.parseInt(invoerEen);
    String invoerTwee = getalTwee.getText();
    int invoerTweeDef = Integer.parseInt(invoerTwee);

    int resultaatDef = invoerEenDef - invoerTweeDef;
    resultaat.setText(Integer.toString(resultaatDef));
}

private void plusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String invoerEen = getalEen.getText();
    int invoerEenDef =  Integer.parseInt(invoerEen);
    String invoerTwee = getalTwee.getText();
    int invoerTweeDef = Integer.parseInt(invoerTwee);

    int resultaatDef = invoerEenDef + invoerTweeDef;
    resultaat.setText(Integer.toString(resultaatDef));
}

private void keerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String invoerEen = getalEen.getText();
    int invoerEenDef =  Integer.parseInt(invoerEen);
    String invoerTwee = getalTwee.getText();
    int invoerTweeDef = Integer.parseInt(invoerTwee);

    int resultaatDef = invoerEenDef * invoerTweeDef;
    resultaat.setText(Integer.toString(resultaatDef));
}

private void delenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String invoerEen = getalEen.getText();
    int invoerEenDef =  Integer.parseInt(invoerEen);
    String invoerTwee = getalTwee.getText();
    int invoerTweeDef = Integer.parseInt(invoerTwee);

    int resultaatDef = invoerEenDef / invoerTweeDef;
    resultaat.setText(Integer.toString(resultaatDef));
}
```

This code contains all the events and the actions they perform (the first one is for subtraction etc...). I use Netbeans as my development environment and I've tried adding try and catch statements like so:

```
try {
        String invoerEen = getalEen.getText();
        int invoerEenDef =  Integer.parseInt(invoerEen);
        String invoerTwee = getalTwee.getText();
        int invoerTweeDef = Integer.parseInt(invoerTwee);

        int resultaatDef = invoerEenDef - invoerTweeDef;
        resultaat.setText(Integer.toString(resultaatDef));
    }
catch(/* what do I put here? */) {
        // what do I do here?
}
```

So my question is, how do I create an exception for when a user enters a value that's not the correct return type (required: Integer, found: String).

Doubles or other return types are not important at the moment, only string.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch when there is a String entered (blank text counts too), use [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html):

```
catch (NumberFormatException n) {
     System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
}
```

To catch *any* error, use [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html):

```
catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Error.");
}
```

---

You can combine these to catch different errors so you can handle them separately. For example:

```
try 
{
    String s = "hi";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s); // will go into NumberFormatException n
    s = s.substring(-2); // will go into Exception e
}
catch (NumberFormatException n) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Unspecified error (not a NumberFormatException).");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **NumberFormatException**. It's thrown when a method that converts a String to a number receives a String that it cannot be converted. like Integer.parseInt("sadfasd");

Answer (score 2):

You can use NumberFormatException [javaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) or Exception e for generic exceptions  and then print a message like: Invalid entry.

```
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, please enter a number");
}
```